# How can I send a single string value through View Form in my webAPI?

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, razor, view

How can I send a single string value through view from in the WebAPI made in ASP.NET core.
Here is my API:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("studentlogin/{value}")]
    public IActionResult StudentLogin(string value)
    {
    string name = String.Concat(value.Where(s => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(s)));
    name =  name.ToLower();
    var newStudent = new Student();
    newStudent.FullName = name;
    db.Entry(newStudent).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.SaveChanges();
    
    var selectStudent = db.Students.Where(ss => ss.FullName == name).FirstOrDefault();
    var id = selectStudent.Id;
    string idToString = id.ToString();
    string answer = sha384converter(idToString);
    selectStudent.HashId = answer;
    db.Entry(selectStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```

I want to send paramenter value in it through View Forms, How can I send data in it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  [Route("studentlogin/{value}")]
> ```

If you are using the above route, the request URL should like this: `https://localhost:44310/api/apicontrollername/studentlogin/XXX`, the parameter will be transferred from the URL and route.

> to send paramenter value in it through View Forms, How can I send data
> in it?

To send parameter value from posted form fields, you could modify the code as below:

In the API controller, remote the route parameter and add the `FromForm` attribute.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("studentlogin")]
    public IActionResult StudentLogin([FromForm]string value)
    {
        string name = "Default value";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        { 
           name  = String.Concat(value.Where(s => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(s)));
        } 

        ... // add your code

        return Ok(name);
    }
```

Then, create a model which contain the value property, like this:

```
public class StudentLoginViewModel
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

In the View page, display the above model in the form:

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.StudentLoginViewModel;
 
<form id="myform">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="value" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="value" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="value" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and add the following script at the end of the above view page:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {  
                //use the serialize() method to encode a set of form elements as a string for submission
                var data = $("#myform").serialize();
                //you can also create JavaScript object and send the data.
                //var data = { value: $("#value").val() };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/todo/studentlogin', // change the url to yours.
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
    })
    </script>
}
```

The result as below:

[image]